# JQuery unable to parse JSON string created by json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, parsing

I am currently in a bind, JQuery is unable to parse the following json strings

```
{ "query":"Unit", 
"suggestions": 
[ {"value":"Mr Ruto Kimutai ","data":88},{"value":"Mr Kimani Karanja","data":79} ] } 

{"query":"Unit",
"suggestions":
[{"value":"Mr Ruto Kimutai ","data":88},{"value":"Mr Kimani Karanja","data":79}]}
```

The above strings when parse through JSON.parse create the following arror:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data at line 1 column 112 of the JSON data

The PHP code which creates the string above is this:

```
public function getCustomerSuggestions($name){

        $customers = $this->model->where('name','LIKE','%'.$name.'%')->show();

        if(count($customers)>=1){

            foreach($customers as $customer){
                $list[] = ['value' => ucfirst($customer->name),'data' => $customer->id];
            }
        }
        else{

            $list[] = ['value' => 'No Customers Found', 'data'=> NULL];
        }

        $full_list['query'] = 'Unit';
        $full_list['suggestions'] = $list;

        return json_encode($full_list);
    }
```

As you can see I am using the function json_encode to create the JSOn string so there should be no issue but it still doesnt work.

Edit
The json is sent using an autocomplete tool called DevBridge Autocomplete which takes the JSON strings and creates a suggestion list. The code I am using is

```
$('input[name=\"customer\"]').devbridgeAutocomplete({
                serviceUrl: '".SITE_PATH."/ajax/admin/quotes/getcustomer',
                minChars: 1,
                onSearchStart: function (query){
                    var searchinput = $(this).val();
                    $('.autocomplete-suggestions').html('Searching: '+searchinput);                   
                },
                onSelect: function(suggestion){   
                    var selection = $(this).val(suggestion.value); 
                    $('input[name=\"customerid\"]').val(suggestion.data);
                    $.get('".SITE_PATH."/ajax/admin/quotes/getcustomerdetails',{id: suggestion.data},
                        function(response){   
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                            $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                                $('#'+key).val(value);
                            });
                        });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please add code of jquery

Comment: are they two separate strings or one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have two JSON objects after each other. That's simply invalid. There can only be a single value at the root of a JSON "document". If you want to send down multiple objects, you need to put them in an array.

It seems `getCustomerSuggestions` is called multiple times and the return value of each call is returned to the client. Instead, the method should return an array, the caller should collect the return values in an array and JSON encode that array.

Comment: The problem is the code generates a list on each progressive keystroke. So each list is generated dynamically

Comment: So? I assume each keystroke is a separate request or is it not? The only thing that matters is that the response of each request is valid.

Comment: Ok let me trace how each response is made

Answer (score 0):

Well, your JSON string is NOT valid.
It should be,

```
[
  { "query":"Unit", 
  "suggestions": 
  [ {"value":"Mr Ruto Kimutai ","data":88},{"value":"Mr Kimani Karanja","data":79} ] } 
  ,
  {"query":"Unit",
  "suggestions":
  [{"value":"Mr Ruto Kimutai ","data":88},{"value":"Mr Kimani Karanja","data":79}]}
]
```

But as Felix Kling said, check your PHP code.